# Php MVC ¿como puedo mostrar el nombre y no el id?

Tags: php, javascript

Me podrian ayudar, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en php (poo) y tengo el siguiente inconveniente, al momento de editar un usuario me aparece el id de la dependencia y no el nombre, lo que se pretende es mostrar el nombre y no el id la dependencia.. Al editar y guardar los datos estos se almacenan normalmente y en el select tambien se muestra, el error esta es al momento de abri el modal que aparece el id y no el nombre, que funcion de javascript deberia ir o como se puede solucionar el problema? Gracias!!

/*=============================================
 EDITAR USUARIO
 =============================================*/

```
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEditarUsuario", function () {

    var idUsuario = $(this).attr("idUsuario");

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (respuesta) {

            $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
            $("#editarDocumento").val(respuesta["documento"]);
            $("#editarUsuario").val(respuesta["usuario"]);
            $("#editarPerfil").html(respuesta["perfil"]);
            $("#editarPerfil").val(respuesta["perfil"]);
            $("#editarDepen").html(respuesta["id_dependencia"]);
            $("#editarDepen").val(respuesta["id_dependencia"]);
            $("#fotoActual").val(respuesta["foto"]);

            $("#passwordActual").val(respuesta["password"]);

            if (respuesta["foto"] != "") {

                $(".previsualizarEditar").attr("src", respuesta["foto"]);

            } else {

                $(".previsualizarEditar").attr("src", "vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonymous.png");

            }

        }

    });

})
```

---

```
<div id="modalEditarUsuario" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!--=====================================
                CABEZA DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Editar usuario</h4>

                </div>

                <!--=====================================
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="box-body">
                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL DOCUMENTO ID -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span> 

                                <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control input-lg" id="editarDocumento" name="editarDocumento" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> 

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="editarNombre" name="editarNombre" required>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR SU DEPENDENCIA -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span> 

                                <select class="form-control input-lg" name="editarDependencia">

                                    <option id="editarDepen"></option>

                                    <?php
                                    $item = null;
                                    $valor = null;

                                    $dependencias = ControladorDependencias::ctrMostrarDependencias($item, $valor);

                                    foreach ($dependencias as $key => $value) {

                                        echo '<option value="' . $value["id"] . '">' . $value["dependencia"] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>


                                </select>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL USUARIO -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> 

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="editarUsuario" name="editarUsuario" value="" readonly>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA LA CONTRASEÑA -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span> 

                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" value="" name="editarPassword" placeholder="Escriba la nueva contraseña">

                                <input type="hidden" id="passwordActual" name="passwordActual">

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR SU PERFIL -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span> 

                                <select class="form-control input-lg" name="editarPerfil">

                                    <option value="" id="editarPerfil"></option>

                                    <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>

                                    <option value="Especial">Especial</option>

                                    <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>

                                </select>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR FOTO -->

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO</div>

                            <input type="file" class="nuevaFoto" name="editarFoto">

                            <p class="help-block">Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

                            <img src="vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonymous.png" class="img-thumbnail previsualizarEditar" width="100px">

                            <input type="hidden" name="fotoActual" id="fotoActual">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--=====================================
                PIE DEL MODAL
                ======================================-->

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar usuario</button>

                </div>

                <?php
                $editarUsuario = new ControladorUsuarios();
                $editarUsuario->ctrEditarUsuario();
                ?> 

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

---

controlador

/* =============================================
      EDITAR USUARIO
      ============================================= */

```
static public function ctrEditarUsuario() {

    if (isset($_POST["editarUsuario"])) {

        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["editarNombre"])&&
            preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["editarDocumento"])&&
                preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["editarDependencia"])){

            /* =============================================
              VALIDAR IMAGEN
              ============================================= */

            $ruta = $_POST["fotoActual"];

            if (isset($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"])) {

                list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                $nuevoAncho = 500;
                $nuevoAlto = 500;

                /* =============================================
                  CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO DONDE VAMOS A GUARDAR LA FOTO DEL USUARIO
                  ============================================= */

                $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"];

                /* =============================================
                  PRIMERO PREGUNTAMOS SI EXISTE OTRA IMAGEN EN LA BD
                  ============================================= */

                if (!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])) {

                    unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);
                } else {

                    mkdir($directorio, 0755);
                }

                /* =============================================
                  DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP
                  ============================================= */

                if ($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") {

                    /* =============================================
                      GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                      ============================================= */

                    $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 999);

                    $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"] . "/" . $aleatorio . ".jpg";

                    $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                    $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                    imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                    imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);
                }

                if ($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/png") {

                    /* =============================================
                      GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                      ============================================= */

                    $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 999);

                    $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"] . "/" . $aleatorio . ".png";

                    $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                    $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                    imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                    imagepng($destino, $ruta);
                }
            }

            $tabla = "usuarios";

            if ($_POST["editarPassword"] != "") {

                if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["editarPassword"])) {

                    $encriptar = crypt($_POST["editarPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
                } else {

                    echo'<script>

                            swal({
                                  type: "error",
                                  title: "¡La contraseña no puede ir vacía o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                                  showConfirmButton: true,
                                  confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                                  }).then(function(result) {
                                    if (result.value) {

                                    window.location = "usuarios";

                                    }
                                })

                        </script>';

                    return;
                }
            } else {

                $encriptar = $_POST["passwordActual"];
            }

            $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["editarNombre"],
                "documento" => $_POST["editarDocumento"],
                "id_dependencia" => $_POST["editarDependencia"],
                "usuario" => $_POST["editarUsuario"],
                "password" => $encriptar,
                "perfil" => $_POST["editarPerfil"],
                "documento" => $_POST["editarDocumento"],
                "foto" => $ruta);

            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlEditarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

            if ($respuesta == "ok") {

                echo'<script>

                swal({
                      type: "success",
                      title: "El usuario ha sido editado correctamente",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      }).then(function(result) {
                                if (result.value) {

                                window.location = "usuarios";

                                }
                            })

                </script>';
            }
        } else {

            echo'<script>

                swal({
                      type: "error",
                      title: "¡El nombre no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      }).then(function(result) {
                        if (result.value) {

                        window.location = "usuarios";

                        }
                    })

            </script>';
        }
    }
}
```

modelo

/* =============================================
      EDITAR USUARIO
      ============================================= */

```
static public function mdlEditarUsuario($tabla, $datos) {

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET nombre = :nombre, password = :password, perfil = :perfil, foto = :foto, documento = :documento, id_dependencia=:id_dependencia WHERE usuario = :usuario");

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":documento", $datos["documento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_dependencia", $datos["id_dependencia"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":foto", $datos["foto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        return "ok";
    } else {

        return "error";
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = null;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En donde es que mostras el id? solo deberias traer el nombre y mostrarlo, si ves el id es porque estas mostrando el id...

Comment: pregunta de donde sale la class `btnEditarUsuario` deberias colocar el codigo completo de tu html.

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho leer, y que no me funciono Ajax y vaya que lo intente, opte por algo así:

cargo los valores desde una datatable con  un botón el truco es asignar un ID a cada registro

```
<td style="font-size:10px;"><?= $i+1?></td>
                <td style="font-size:10px;"><span id="Activo<?= 
$i+1?>"><?=$Activo?></span></td> 
                <td style="font-size:10px;"><span 
id="Subactivo<?= $i+1?>"><?=$Subactivo?></span></td>`
```

y al hacer clic se envían los datos a la función javascript /jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.transfer', function(){
  var id=$(this).val();
  var Activo=$('#Activo'+id).text();
  var Subactivo=$('#Subactivo'+id).text();
  $('#transfer').modal('show');
  $('#eActivo').val(Activo);
  $('#eSubactivo').val(Subactivo);
    });
  });
```

En el  modal los muestro asi:

```
<td style="font-size:10px;"><span ><input type="text" 
style="width:70px;" class="form-control" id="eActivo" 
readonly="true"></span></td> 
 <td style="font-size:10px;"><span ><input type="text" 
style="width:35px;" class="form-control" id="eSubactivo" 
readonly="true"></span></td>`
```

Se que es diferente a lo que estas aplicando, pero como una referencia quizás te pueda ser de utilidad la forma en que se pasa el parámetro o valor.